# Нужна ли запятая перед последним союзом "и"? Объясните, пожалуйста, ответ

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, и

> Более того, для Репина в Лицее была устроена инсценировка экзамена, в
> которой принимали участие не только воспитанники, но и преподаватели,
> и даже директор Лицея.

Comment: Ссылка на цитату: https://urok.1sept.ru/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8/538486/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая перед последним союзом "и" не нужна.

*Более того, для Репина в Лицее была устроена инсценировка экзамена, в которой принимали участие **не только** воспитанники, **но и** преподаватели и даже директор.*

Здесь нет ситуации с повторяющимся союзом. Первый "и" входит в состав парного союза "не только... но и", а второй соединяет однородные члены.

P. S. Хотя союз "и" может быть присоединительным (тогда запятая перед ним ставится), не думаю, что в данном случае такая трактовка будет оправданной. Особая выделительная пауза здесь не просматривается.

Comment: На мой взгляд, запятая здесь была бы _ошибкой_. Дело даже не в паузе, а в _смысле_ высказывания: присоединительное значение союза в этом примере невозможно, поскольку "директор" не принадлежит к числу "преподавателей",- отсюда однородность соединяемых союзом членов предложения.

Comment: @Alex_ander Спасибо за комментарий!

Answer (score 2):

Интересный вопрос! Сначала  я была полностью согласна с ответом нашего участника Александр Стрелец, никаких сомнений не было. Впрочем, я и сейчас согласна, но есть некоторое дополнение.

Меня заинтересовал **комментарий**, в котором Alex_ander  не допускает присоединительное значение второго союза И.  Я решила, что  запреты мне не нравятся, а  допускать нужно по возможности всё.  Надо просто найти другой присоединительный союз для последней фразы, но  союз никак не находился.

Однако по ходу действия у меня возникли **сомнения другого рода.**  А почему здесь **нет повторяющегося союза И…И?**  Перечислительная интонация вполне возможна. А если предположить, что это **сложный по структуре двойной союз** «не только…но и…и»? То есть во второй его  части однородные члены соединены повторяющимся союзом И…И.

Тогда получается, что второй вариант тоже возможен, а задача имеет два решения (хотя первый вариант мне нравится больше):

(2)  *Более того, для Репина в Лицее была устроена инсценировка экзамена, в которой принимали участие **не только воспитанники, но и преподаватели, и даже директор Лицея.***

Но такие сложные двойные союзы мне что-то не встречались, а вам?  Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.